# PostgreSQL - ERROR: invalid privilege type CREATE for sequence

Tags: database, postgresql, sequence

is it possible to allow a user to create sequences in a schema without allowing him to create tables, functions, stored procedures, etc?

This is my current set of SQL commands so far:

```
   REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA sales FROM sales_user;
   REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA sales FROM sales_user;
   REVOKE ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA sales FROM sales_user;
   REVOKE ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA sales FROM sales_user;

   GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA sales TO sales_user;
   GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA sales TO sales_user;
   GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA sales TO sales_user;
>> GRANT CREATE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA sales TO sales_user;
   GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA sales TO sales_user;
```

Everything works well, but the line that is marked generates

```
ERROR:  invalid privilege type CREATE for sequence
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no privilege in PostgreSQL that grants or denies the creation of certain objects.

All you need is the `CREATE` privilege on a schema, then you can create anything you want in that schema.

So there is no way to achieve what you want.